# Laravel "FatalErrorException in User.php line 8:"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

What does this mean, and how do I fix it??

```
FatalErrorException in User.php line 8:
Class App\User contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthIdentifierName, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthIdentifier, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthPassword, ...)
```

It happened when I was trying to log into my dashboard for my laravel app.

Comment: Can you post the User.php class? It looks like your class is not implementing some of the methods from the abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

This is about the interface implements. If you want to implement the interface, you need to mention all the methods which interface declared.

> Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable

The interface definition:

```
interface Authenticatable {

    public function getAuthIdentifierName();
    public function getAuthIdentifier();
    public function getAuthPassword();
    public function getRememberToken();
    public function setRememberToken($value);
    public function getRememberTokenName();

}
```

So your User class must have the methods above.

```
class User implements   Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
{
    public function getAuthIdentifierName() {}
    public function getAuthIdentifier(){}
    public function getAuthPassword(){}
    public function getRememberToken(){}
    public function setRememberToken($value){}
    public function getRememberTokenName(){}

}
```

Even you do not want write code in those method, however,  you still need to write empty method in your user class.

Solution:

1. The interface mainly used for **Auth** mechanism. If you do not want use for **Auth**, you just remove your Authenticatable interface from your User class.
2. If you need it use for **Auth**, you need to implement all the interface methods and get it right. More information please read the following websites:

   - [Laravel doc: Custom User Provider and Authenticatable Class](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers)
   - [How do I create a custom auth in laravel 5](http://laravel.io/forum/11-04-2014-laravel-5-how-do-i-create-a-custom-auth-in-laravel-5)
   - [Replacing the laravel authentication with a custom authentication](https://laracasts.com/index.php/discuss/channels/laravel/replacing-the-laravel-authentication-with-a-custom-authentication)